# Proving limit of difference is $0$: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} [(n+1)^{\frac{1}{7}} - (n)^{\frac{1}{7}}] = 0$

Tags: limits, radicals

I am trying to show that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} [(n+1)^{\frac{1}{7}} - (n)^{\frac{1}{7}}] = 0$$

and I know intuitively this must be so since the "+1" contribution in the first term becomes negligible as $n$ becomes sufficiently large. I am wondering whether showing the ratio between the two terms approaching $1$ is sufficient to show the difference is $0$; if so, how can this be formalized? If not, how can it more directly be shown that the difference approaches $0$?

Comment: By the Binomial Theorem, $\left(n^{1/7}+\frac{1}{7n^{6/7}}\right)^7\gt n+1$, so $0\lt (n+1)^{1/7}-n^{1/7}\lt \frac{1}{7n^{6/7}}$. Now Squeeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[(n+1)^{\frac{1}{7}}-n^{\frac{1}{7}}\right]\;,$$ Now let $$\displaystyle n= \frac{1}{y}\;,$$ Then $y\rightarrow 0$

So $$\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{7}}-1}{y^{\frac{1}{7}}} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{7}}-1}{(1+y)-1}\cdot \frac{y}{y^{\frac{1}{7}}} = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{7}}-1}{(1+y)-1}\cdot \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}y^{\frac{6}{7}} = \frac{1}{7}\times 0 = 0$$

Above we used the formula $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = na^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
a^7-b^7 = (a-b)(a^6+a^5b+a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^2b^4+ab^5+b^6)
$$

So for $a=\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } $ and $b = \sqrt [ 7 ]{n  } $, we get:

$$
\lim _{ n\rightarrow +\infty  }{ \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } -\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n } \quad  } \quad =\quad \lim _{ n\rightarrow +\infty  }{ \frac { n+1-n }{ (\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 6 }+((\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } ))^{ 5 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) +(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 4 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 2 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 3 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 3 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 2 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 4 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 5 }+\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 6 } } \quad  } \\ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad =\quad \lim _{ n\rightarrow +\infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ (\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 6 }+((\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } ))^{ 5 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) +(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 4 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 2 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 3 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 3 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )^{ 2 }\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 4 }+(\sqrt [ 7 ]{ n+1 } )\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 5 }+\left( \sqrt [ 7 ]{ n }  \right) ^{ 6 } } \quad  } \\ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad =\quad 0
$$

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If we can set $a=(n+1)^{\frac 17}$ and $b=n^{\frac 17}$, then the expression becomes $$\lim_{n \to \infty} [a-b]=0.$$ It suffices to prove that $$a-b \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

The Binomial Theorem at degree $7$ gives us
$$a^7-b^7=(a-b)(a^6+a^5b+a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^2b^4+ab^5+b^6). \tag{$\star$}$$
We have
\begin{align}
a-b
&= \frac{a^7-b^7}{a^6+a^5b+a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^2b^4+ab^5+b^6} \quad \text{by } (\star)\\
&= \frac 1{a^6+a^5b+a^4b^2+a^3b^3+a^2b^4+ab^5+b^6} \\
&\to 0
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.

Explanations for the above steps:

- $a^7-b^7=[(n+1)^{\frac 17}]^7-[n^{\frac 17}]^7=(n+1)-n=1$
- $a =(n+1)^{\frac 17} \to \infty$ and $b = n^{\frac 17} \to \infty$
- The variables $a$ and $b$ are in only the denominator for the penultimate step above.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\left(\sqrt[7]{n+1}\right)^7-\left(\sqrt[7]{n}\right)^7=\left(\sqrt[7]{n+1}-\sqrt[7]{n}\right)\left(\sqrt[7]{(n+1)^6}+\cdots\sqrt[7]{n^6}\right)=1,$$

where we have used the identity

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right),$$

which holds for odd $n$. Then,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[7]{n+1}-\sqrt[7]{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[7]{(n+1)^6}+\cdots\sqrt[7]{n^6}}=0,$$

since the denominator is going to $\infty$ and the numerator is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering whether showing the ratio between the two terms approaching 1 is sufficient to show the difference is 0"

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x + 1}{x} = 1$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{ (x + 1) - (x)} \ne 0$

One approach to proving your limit would be to let $n = 1/x$ and let $x\to 0^+$. Then apply L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor expansion of $(1 + x)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha x + o(x)$:
\begin{align*}
& (n + 1)^{1/7} - n^{1/7} \\
= & n^{1/7}\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/7} - 1\right] \\
= & n^{1/7}\left(1 + \frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{n^{6/7}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{6/7}}\right)\\
\to & 0
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Why is the downvote? Please leave the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}[(n+1)^{1/7}-n^{1/7}]$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[n^{1/7}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/7}-n^{1/7}\right]$$ Using binomial expansion of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/7}$ & neglecting higher power terms 
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[n^{1/7}\left(1+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{n}\right)-n^{1/7}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[n^{1/7}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{n^{1/7}}{n}-n^{1/7}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{n^{6/7}}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{7}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^{6/7}}\right]=0$$

Answer (score -4):

Divide by $(n)^{1/7}$:

$$\begin{align}\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^{1/7} -1\right]&=0\\1-1&=0\\0&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: you can't just divide you can factorise and then get $0\times\infty$ which is undefined. So it's wrong :/

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Could you clarify? I don't exactly understand what you are saying.

Comment: you divided and multiplied at the same time so for the division you got $0$ but you forgot that you're still mutliplying with $\sqrt[7]{n}$ which tends to $\infty$ and that has no value as it is undefined

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} 1= 0$. Proof: divide by $n$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac1x= 0$